# Как написать поиск-фильтрацию по всем типам?

Tags: c#, linq

Делаю фильтрацию по полям. Изначально был вариант, поиск только по string, и что бы поиск был Equal. Теперь хотел, усложнить задачу, что бы была фильтрация по Contains, и заодно что бы можно было искать по всем типам, типу int / decimal / double ...

```
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetExpression<T, R>(string propertyName, R propertyValue)
        {
            var parametr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
            var property = Expression.Property(parametr, propertyName);
            var containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(R) });
 
            var objectContains = Expression.Constant(propertyValue, typeof(R));
            var objectEquals   = Expression.Equal(property, Expression.Constant(propertyValue));
 
            var constrantMethod = Expression.Call(property, containsMethod, objectContains);
 
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(constrantMethod, parametr)
                .Or(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(objectEquals, parametr));
        }
 
        public static IQueryable<T> ApplyFiltering<T, R>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyLabel, R propertyValue)
        {
            var propertyNames = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                              .Where(property => property.PropertyType == typeof(R) && property.Name == propertyLabel)
                              .Select(x => x.Name);
 
            var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<T>();
 
            foreach (var name in propertyNames)
            {
                predicate = predicate.Or(GetExpression<T, R>(name, propertyValue));
            }
 
            return source.Where(predicate);
        }
```

Comment: По всем типам - `object`. В предыдущем вашем вопросе я в моём ответе использовал object - проверял код со строковыми и числовыми типами - работает.

Comment: Э-э-э... `Contains` есть смысл в применении к строкам. Но нет к числам.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо. учту про object. а как тогда работать с числами? если не contains?

Comment: @A.Laketych: А это зависит от того, какую задачу вы решаете. По идее. нужно спросить у PM-а или у клиента, что именно ему нужно